# Examples of hard instances for Goemans and Williamson algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, approximation-algorithms, max-cut, hard-instances

I'm interested in the explicit examples of graphs for which application of Goemans and Williamson algorithm for approximating maximum cuts results in 0.878…-approximation factor.

The algorithm to create such instances would be perfect, explicit examples and references are satisfactory.

Comment: I wonder if you have read this paper http://www.eccc.uni-trier.de/report/2005/101/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess this reference is about what you ask:

> N. Alon, B. Sudakov, and U. Zwick. [Constructing worst case instances for semidefinite programming based approximation algorithms](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bsudakov/worst-case-instances.pdf). SIAM Journalon Discrete Mathematics, 15:58–72, 2002.

This is an excerpt from it (p.60):

> ... we present the construction of the
>   graphs that show that the local analysis of the MAX CUT algorithms of [GW95]
>   and [Zwi99] are tight.